# Crash in store services - iOS 11

Tags: ios, crash, ios11

I am receiving crashes with our live app with this message. And this is only for iOS 11 users, but not able to reproduce it at my end. Any idea why this could be? How to debug and resolve it?

The crash happens in below method call:

- [SSRequest _shutdownRequestWithMessageID:]

Answer (score 0):

Try to update to the latest version (7.25.0) Google-Mobile-Ads-SDK, it seems it was fixed here in the release notes

7.24.1   2017‑9‑27 Updates the way the SDK interacts with Apple's StoreServices.

Listed here https://developers.google.com/admob/ios/rel-notes